# Null exception when using filter on aggregation helper ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, unit-testing, elasticsearch, moq

I created an `AggregationsHelper` object and I called `.Filter` method on it

```
 var aggr = new AggregationsHelper();
 aggr .Filter("test");
```

I get a null exception when calling the `.Filter` function. Do I have to initiate the object somehow?

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by @Val, I have to pass a dictionary to the object via the constructor

My real question is how to mock such complex ElasticSearch aggregation query:

```
    var res = ElasticClient.Search<DataRecord>(s => s
            .SearchType(SearchType.Count)
            .Aggregations(a => a.Filter(
                "histIdFilter",
                f => f.Filter(
                    f2 => f2.Term(
                        t => t.HistoryId,
                        groupId))
            .Aggregations(ag => ag.Filter("timeRangeFilter", fg => fg.Filter(fg2 => fg2.Range(i => i.OnField(b => b.DateTime))))))));

    // Applying filter
    var ah = res.Aggs;
    var histIdAgg = ah.Filter("histIdFilter");
    var timeRangeAgg = histIdAgg.Filter("timeRangeFilter");
```

I successfully managed to mock the `.Aggr` property of the query response, using

```
datResp.SetupGet(x => x.Aggs).Returns(ah.Object);
```

but when I call `.Filter` on the `ah` object I get a null exception like if the internal dictionary was not set for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when creating an `AggregationsHelper` without passing a dictionary, you'll get a null pointer exception [on this line](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/5b1ada2a9fc9d2f2d9e4168ece7ae8e7d7b01724/src/Nest/Domain/Aggregations/AggregationsHelper.cs#L25). Try like this instead:

```
var temp = new Dictionary<string, IAggregation>();
var aggr = new AggregationsHelper(temp);
aggr.Filter("test");
```

Comment: brilliant. This lead to my real question which is another one. I need to mock a NEST ElasticSearch query. Please, see my edit for the question